# Is it possible for a plugin to be universally present

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Can we create a plugin using JH toolkit which can be accessible from anywhere inside the FI's OLB?

Should navigation menu be used to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins can be placed in multiple locations within the Banno platform, but the standard plugin Link Type places your plugin on the Dashboard. The Dashboard is visible in both Banno mobile and online to all users.

I'd recommend watching the `Let's talk about plugins` video posted on https://jackhenry.dev/ for more basic information about building your first plugin.